# Norm_S_Dist in Mac Excel 2011 Compile error: Method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to run a script written for Excel 2010 on my Mac running Excel 2011.

The line creating the error is:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d1, True)
```

The error is **Compile error: Method or data member not found**

I have tried running it as:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm.S.Dist(d1, True)
```

as it would be called if typing it into a cell in a worksheet but this gives the same error.

The last thing I tried is:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d1, True)
```

The error is **Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.**

Any idea how to get this command to work on a Mac?  The Mac is running OS X, 10.8.4.

Comment: `NormSDist` is taking a different no. of arguments. See this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.normsdist.aspx

Comment: They are two different functions and it appears that Norm_S_Dist isn't implement in the Mac VBA.  Workarounds would be to either reproduce the function yourself in VBA or use a temporary worksheet to calculate the value in a cell and read that in.

Comment: Thanks @CuberChase.  Unfortunately, I am so unfamiliar with VBA, I wouldn't know where to start.  I have an old PC that I will upgrade excel on and run it there for now.